# Capitalisation after the ¡ signo de exclamación de apertura

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, uso-de-mayúsculas

Do I need to put a capital letter after the ¡ symbol? e.g. are these sentences wrong or right:

> - Vale, ¡hasta pronto!
> - Tengo ganas de verte, ¡hace tanto calor aquí ahora mismo!

Comment: They are correct. Check the explanation and examples in *Nueva gramática de la lengua española (2009). [Edición en línea (www.rae.es)* http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/z.cgi?t=07655174732867256745210206&s=1&ap=42.14d

Comment: @Rotten - Sounds like an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Short story: exclamation marks may put emphasis in a given part of the sentence or the whole sentence. Just try to imagine the sentence without exclamation marks:

> Vale, hasta pronto.

This is a perfectly valid sentence, so the next step would be to make emphasis in a given region:

> Vale, ¡hasta pronto!
>   ¡Vale, hasta pronto!

The introduction of the exclamation marks does not affect the capitalization, unless you divide the sentence:

> ¡Vale! ¡Hasta pronto!

In this case you have two separated sentences and hence you need to start the second one with a capital letter, the same as you do in English:

> All right! See you soon!